# Convert JSON Object to URL Params / MVC3 / JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

If I have an object array like this...

```
var p = [{ 'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe' }, { 'first': 'Sue', 'last': 'Smith' }];
```

And I need to append it to the URL like this...

```
/myapp/myaction?p[0].first=John&p[0].last=Doe&p[1].first=Sue&p[1].last=Smith
```

Is there something in JQuery that will help me do this without having to process it manually?

Basically, I have an object like the people array, and I need to send it to ASP MVC3 in a format that it will understand and bind to a list. MVC3 understands nested items encoded in the "dot" format (e.g. p[0].first).

Comment: FYI `{ first='John', last='Doe' }` is not a valid JSON object, it should be at least `{ 'first':'John', 'last':'Doe' }`

Comment: Thanks, I was writing quickly and did not check the code. I will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be an even better way, but something like this should work:

```
var params = $.map(p, function(n, i){
    return "p[" + i + "].first=" + n.first + "&p[" + i + "].last=" + n.last;
}).join("&");
```

If the properties of the objects are dynamic, you could use a `for...in` to loop over them.

Comment: Thanks! This worked well. I was thinking there might be an existing method in JQuery that might do this, but this was super easy.